# Docker: Build fails with error unknown parent image ID

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm facing intermittent build job failures with the below error.

```
[0munknown parent image ID sha256:478c35b0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: Consider adding more details. What are you trying to do, how did you get there?

Comment: I'm hitting this on Jenkins and it seems nondeterministic. My command is just `docker build --rm --tag foo:bar .`

Comment: can you send what you see with command docker image ls

Answer (score 5):

This generally occurs when you simultaneously clean up the docker memory (or someone delete the content of /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content or run docker system prune at the same time) , so the image you are building unable to locate the parent folder in which image data is present.
Make sure this wont be happening at same time  and restarts the build.

Comment: This feels like a bug in docker, that it would delete an image that was in use.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an image with `none` name, then you need to remove this and rebuild your container. That's what solved it for me.

Comment: Comment on the behalf of Craft: *Can you send what do you see with docker image ls ?*

Comment: please ask for clarification only in the comments.

Comment: It's not at all clear _why_ this works, but it did solve the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same concern when building a docker image. The error message I got is below:

```
[Docker] ERROR: Failed to create docker image: Could not build image: unknown parent image ID sha256:cc0b3bd844b13a2ebfc6915019a8194538f2d0b41e420b76a20702e985e2a298
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not build image: unknown parent image ID sha256:cc0b3bd844b13a2ebfc6915019a8194538f2d0b41e420b76a20702e985e2a298
```

What worked for me was just trying to rebuild the image again, and it worked fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Use the **--no-cache** tag in the build command line.

```
docker build --no-cache -t dockerimagenew:v1 .
```

Answer (score 0):

This *can* be a flake on various machines with shared disk between `docker` processes, e.g. Buildkite instances. Simply restarting the build worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To **prevent** this from happening, perform all docker "cleanup" operations (with `docker system prune` and `docker rmi`) in such a way that no build pipeline (with `docker build`) can be running at the same time as the cleanup process.

Assuming that your cleanup operations are also automated with Jenkins, you can **try to make the cleanup and build pipelines non-overlapping.**

One (imperfect) solution is the [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/PrioritySorter/), using which you can:

- put all build pipelines and the cleanup pipeline in two different *Job Groups* and
- make these two groups mutually exclusive with `runExclusive: true`.

It's imperfect as it does not affect running pipelines retroactively.

---

This problem is caused by a **Docker build cache misses** that were not predictable in advance (when the failing build started), because the relevant layers disappeared from the build cache at a later stage of the (long-running) build, removed by some other heavy-handed "cleanup" process.

To **verify** that this is the reason, check that the digest displayed by Jenkins docker plugin in its error message is indeed missing from the local images cache:

```
# given this Jenkins docker plugin error message:
unknown parent image ID sha256:a7b0fc09ca549c852550f050ef2079663232405f0e3abd5c1a0051f30eb448f4

# ... let's search for the missing digest:
$ docker images --digests | grep a7b0fc09ca549c852550f050ef2079663232405f0e3abd5c1a0051f30eb448f4
$
```